# Matplotlib notebook backend export resolution

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am using Jupyter Notebook with matplotlib and the notebook backend. Sometimes, I hit the "Stop Interaction" button to be able to drag and drop the figure to another software (e.g. for quick and dirty presentations).

For this purpose, however, the default resolution of the figures is a bit too low so they look blurry. I know, that I can use something like

```
mpl.rcParams.update({'figure.dpi': 150})
```

to increase the figure resolution but that makes them quite large in the notebook (too large to be handy).

So my question is, if there is an option to set the "final rendering resolution" that is applied when I hit the "Stop Interaction" button. Basically such that one resolution is used for the interactive part, and another one for the "inline rendering".

Comment: If you drag the figure (the png image) it will not change its resolution. If anything, you could save the figure with a different dpi and use that saved figure in the other software (dragging from your file explorer instead of the notebook). Else, you might be able to intercept the close-event of the figure and display a larger figure in your notebook, but that would probably lead to two figures appearing.

Comment: For this use-case, I would like to avoid having to save the figure separately. The second scenario you describe is what I would like to achieve. Do you know if there is something like this built-in?
To me, it anyway looks like the figure is re-rendered when I quit that Stop Interaction button (as if some anti-aliasing is applied or so).